# What exactly is selenese html?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have been using selenium IDE to do some web app testing. I have been encountering errors on trying to playback the user actions, but have not been able to fix them because I have no idea what makes up selenese html targets and commands. It does not look like normal html to me but I cannot figure it out. If someone would be so kind as to help me I would be very happy.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a table definition with three tds per tr, specifying the command and any other parameters needed.

Example from [the docs](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#script-syntax):

```
<table>
    <tr><td>open</td><td></td><td>/download/</td></tr>
    <tr><td>assertTitle</td><td></td><td>Downloads</td></tr>
    <tr><td>verifyText</td><td>//h2</td><td>Downloads</td></tr>
</table>
```

The IDE also has a reference built into it. I suggest you peruse the documentation available on their site until you are comfortable with the way the IDE works -- it can be a little unintuitive if you haven't done so.

Comment: Do you have any idea how it decides what to call different elements?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean how it selects elements on the page, there's quite a few options. You can use XPATH or CSS selectors,  etc. They're layed out in the docs. If you mean how it knows which tds to use for parameters, it's whatever it says in the docs (and the API). If you mean something else by "what to call different elements", I'm afraid I'll need an example of what you're talking about.

Comment: Is it just me or is this "table-like" syntax absolutely horrible? Are there no alternatives?

Answer (score 10):

[Selenese](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#selenium-commands-selenese) is a **high level**, cross-platform and language-independent convention for representing Selenium commands.

The term ''Selenese HTML'' is less to do with [how you'd target elements in the HTML user interface](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#locating-elements) of the application under test and is more *a description of how the commands are formatted*.

So, I use the term ''Selenese HTML'' to distinguish it from Selenese in other languages/formats such as Selenese PHP, Selenese Java etc.

There are up to 3 components to a Selenese command:

- commandName
- 1st argument (required by some commands)
- 2nd argument (required by some commands)

Given this knowledge, we can write the command in HTML format as a row of an HTML table, where each cell of the row represents a component of the command

```
----------------------------------------------
| commandName | 1st argument | 2nd argument |
----------------------------------------------
```

Now that the command is written in HTML form, we could potentially share it on the World Wide Web so that **both** humans and machines can read and understand it.

Answer (score 5):

The [Selenium Reference](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html) page would be a good place to start to learn about what all the various commands do and how to use them.